# Remember state of collapse / JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this JS/Bootstrap on my element to open and close, I want to some how remember the state even after switching to a new page.

```js
<script>
     $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
   $('#menu-wrap').toggleClass('closed');
   $('#menu-wrap').toggleClass('open');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so, you may need to store the state of that collapsible at some place in app. You can put the state in localstorage and also keep updating it whenever there is a change in the state of collpasible.

Somewhat like -

```js
var toggleState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("menuToggle"));

if( toggleState == true || toggleState == false){
  toggleState == true ? $('#menu-wrap').toggleClass('open'): '';
}

$('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
  //$('#menu-wrap').toggleClass('closed'); you dont need this and keep the menu by default hidden
  $('#menu-wrap').toggleClass('open');
    
    localStorage.setItem("menuToggle", $('#menu-wrap').hasClass("open"));
});
```